# Fail to push project to Heroku. Error: command "gcc -pthread..." solution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, heroku

I am trying to push a project to heroku from Mac with local git repository. There seem to be a few errors that are being encountered:

1. "error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result..." failed with exit status=1
2. Failed building wheel for numpy
3. Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

and a warning: "WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
remote:              You should consider upgrading via the '/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

Is there a way to solve this? I tried to upgrade pip version locally, but this did not seem to help.
In my requirements.txt file I had numpy==1.19.3.

Please see the below terminal output:

```
    set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
(virtualenv_name) (base) user@userMacbook MyApp % git push heroku master             
Enumerating objects: 21, done.
Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 100.27 KiB | 5.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
 Compressing source files... done.
 Building source:
 
 -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
 -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 -----> Python app detected
 -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.4
        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
 -----> Installing python-3.10.4
 -----> Installing pip 22.0.4, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
 -----> Installing SQLite3
 -----> Installing requirements with pip
        Collecting appdirs==1.4.4
          Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
        …
        Collecting h5py==3.1.0
          Downloading h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)
          Installing build dependencies: started
          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
          Installing backend dependencies: started
          Installing backend dependencies: still running...
          Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error'
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
          
          × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
          │ exit code: 1
          ╰─> [963 lines of output]
              Ignoring Cython: markers 'python_version < "3.8"' don't match your environment
              Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
              Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
              Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8"' don't match your environment
              Collecting Cython>=0.29.14
                Downloading Cython-0.29.30-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
                   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.9/1.9 MB 87.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
              Collecting pkgconfig
                Downloading pkgconfig-1.5.5-py3-none-any.whl (6.7 kB)
              Collecting numpy==1.19.3
                Downloading numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
                   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 116.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
                Installing build dependencies: started
                Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
                Getting requirements to build wheel: started
                Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
                Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
                Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
              Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
                Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
                Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): still running...
                Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
                error: subprocess-exited-with-error
              
                × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
                │ exit code: 1
                ╰─> [928 lines of output]
                    setup.py:67: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.19.3 may not yet support Python 3.10.
                      warnings.warn(
                    Running from numpy source directory.
                    Cythonizing sources
                    numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in has not changed
                    numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx has not changed
                    …
                    numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in has not changed
                    blas_opt_info:
                    blas_mkl_info:
                    customize UnixCCompiler
                      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    …
              
                    accelerate_info:
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    /tmp/pip-install-107dlw87/numpy_1890b2f208354b3dbd1e2ffea43648ce/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
                        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
                        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
                        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
                        Blas library.
                      if self._calc_info(blas):
                    blas_info:
                      libraries blas not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    /tmp/pip-install-107dlw87/numpy_1890b2f208354b3dbd1e2ffea43648ce/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
                        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
                        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
                        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
                        the BLAS environment variable.
                      if self._calc_info(blas):
                    blas_src_info:
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    /tmp/pip-install-107dlw87/numpy_1890b2f208354b3dbd1e2ffea43648ce/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
                        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
                        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
                        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
                        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
                      if self._calc_info(blas):
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
                    lapack_opt_info:
                    lapack_mkl_info:
                      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    openblas_lapack_info:
                      libraries openblas not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    openblas_clapack_info:
                      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    flame_info:
                      libraries flame not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
                    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
                      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
                      …
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    atlas_3_10_info:
                      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
                      …
                      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
                    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    atlas_threads_info:
                    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
                      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
                      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
                      …
                    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    atlas_info:
                      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /app/.heroku/python/lib
                        …
                      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
                    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    lapack_info:
                      libraries lapack not found in ['/app/.heroku/python/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    /tmp/pip-install-107dlw87/numpy_1890b2f208354b3dbd1e2ffea43648ce/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
                        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
                        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
                        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
                        the LAPACK environment variable.
                      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
                    lapack_src_info:
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    /tmp/pip-install-107dlw87/numpy_1890b2f208354b3dbd1e2ffea43648ce/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
                        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
                        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
                        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
                        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
                      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
                      NOT AVAILABLE
              
                    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
                      FOUND:
                        language = c
                        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
              
                    /tmp/pip-build-env-tn8_t__2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
                      warnings.warn(msg)
                    running bdist_wheel
                    running build
                    running config_cc
                    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
                    running config_fc
                    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
                    running build_src
                    build_src
                    building py_modules sources
                    building library "npymath" sources
                    Could not locate executable gfortran
                    Could not locate executable f95
                    Could not locate executable ifort
                    Could not locate executable ifc
                    Could not locate executable lf95
                    Could not locate executable pgfortran
                    Could not locate executable nvfortran
                    Could not locate executable f90
                    Could not locate executable f77
                    Could not locate executable fort
                    Could not locate executable efort
                    Could not locate executable efc
                    Could not locate executable g77
                    Could not locate executable g95
                    Could not locate executable pathf95
                    Could not locate executable nagfor
                    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
                      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
                    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
                    building library "npysort" sources
                      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
                    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
                    building library "npyrandom" sources
                    building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
                    building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
                      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath' to include_dirs.
                      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
                      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
                    numpy.core - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/funcs.inc', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/matmul.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/clip.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common/templ_common.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h']
                    building extension "numpy.core._umath_tests" sources
                    …
                    building extension "numpy.linalg.lapack_lite" sources
                    ### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
                    building extension "numpy.linalg._umath_linalg" sources
                    ### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
                    building extension "numpy.random._mt19937" sources
                    …
                    building extension "numpy.random.mtrand" sources
                    building data_files sources
                    build_src: building npy-pkg config files
                    running build_py
                    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
                    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy
                    copying numpy/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy
                    copying numpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy
                    … (removed to make more concise)
                    copying numpy/tests/test_scripts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/tests
                    running build_clib
                    customize UnixCCompiler
                    customize UnixCCompiler using new_build_clib
                    building 'npymath' library
                    compiling C sources
                    C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC
              
                    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
                    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy
                    …
                    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath
                    compile options: '-Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
                    extra options: '-std=c99'
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.cgcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
              
                    gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
                    ar: adding 4 object files to build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/libnpymath.a
                    building 'npysort' library
                    compiling C sources
                    C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC
              
                    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npysort
                    compile options: '-Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -…
                    …
                    compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
                    extra options: '-std=c99'
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.cgcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/common.c
              
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c
                    …
                    gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘float_arrtype_hash’:
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2967:27: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
                     2967 |     return _Py_HashDouble((double) PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj, @name@))
                    In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                                     from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
                    /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
                       10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
                          |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2967:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
                     2967 |     return _Py_HashDouble((double) PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj, @name@))
                          |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                                     from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
                    /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
                       10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
                          |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘cfloat_arrtype_hash’:
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2975:31: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘_Py_HashDouble’
                     2975 |     hashreal = _Py_HashDouble((double)
                          |                               ^~~~~~~~
                          |                               |
                          |                               double
                     2976 |             PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj, C@name@).real);
                          |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                                     from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
                    /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
                       10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
                          |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2975:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
                     2975 |     hashreal = _Py_HashDouble((double)
                          |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    …(removed some text for clarity)
                          |                           double
                    In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                                     from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
                    /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:38: note: expected ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} but argument is of type ‘double’
                       10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
                          |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2997:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘_Py_HashDouble’
                     2997 |     return _Py_HashDouble(npy_half_to_double(PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj, Half)));
                          |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/Python.h:77,
                                     from numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:3:
                    /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10/pyhash.h:10:23: note: declared here
                       10 | PyAPI_FUNC(Py_hash_t) _Py_HashDouble(PyObject *, double);
                          |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘longdouble_arrtype_hash’:
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2968:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
                     2968 | }
                          | ^
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘float_arrtype_hash’:
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2968:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
                     2968 | }
                          | ^
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src: In function ‘half_arrtype_hash’:
                    numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2998:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
                     2998 | }
                          | ^
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/vdot.c
                    …
                    /src/umath/clip.c
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c
                    gcc: numpy/core/src/umath/extobj.c
                    gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c
                    error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
                    [end of output]
              
                note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
                ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
              Failed to build numpy
              ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
              WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
              You should consider upgrading via the '/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
              [end of output]
          
          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
        
        × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> See above for output.
        
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 
  !     Push failed
 Verifying deploy...
 
 !  Push rejected to app-name.
 
To https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git'
```

Comment: Why are you only showing the last few lines of your error output? All the important information is cut off. Please [edit] your question and show us _all_ of it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I added more of the terminal input and output, trimming some things to keep it under the character count.

Comment: Read the warnings and errors: it's pretty clear that numpy isn't ready to use Python 3.10 yet. (I don't use Heroku, but there's probably some Heroku setting to use an older Python version.)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I used an earlier version of python with runtime.txt and it worked!